# Version 4.0 localhost testing getting 3228 : The ThreeDSNotificationURL field format is invalid

Tags: opayo

I am currently testing the changes for version 4.0 of the protocol for PSD2 using Direct Integration.

I am running under Visual Studio using a localhost website address.

When calling the SagePay payment endpoint with ThreeDSNotificationURL set as a localhost address (http://localhost:15536/Payments/ThreeDResponse) I receive the following error '3228 : The ThreeDSNotificationURL field format is invalid.'

If I change this field to a fully qualified domain (http://www.google.com) I no longer receive the error, but can't complete my testing.

Using localhost for the termurl in version 3.0 of the protocol works as expected.

Comment: The version 4 reference does say that the address should be fully qualified unfortunately so I'm not sure it can be tested in this way.

https://www.sagepay.co.uk/library/document/directintegrationandprotocol4guidelinespdf

I wonder whether it would accept a HTTPS localhost URI or whether it is necessary to use a staging server or Ngrok to obtain a fully qualified domain name for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you URL encode the ThreeDSNotificationURL in your post?
I send it like that and it is ok:
sb.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://www.clientdomian.com/ac/ThreeDSNotificationURL.aspx"));
I run the site on my local IIS for development.

Comment: I do URL encode the ThreeDSNotificationURL in the post. I'm running directly from Visual Studio which is how I get the localhost:portnumber url format. Are you publishing your solution and have a local DNS setting to resolve  clientdomain.com to your local development machine?

Comment: Here how I do it locally: I create the website in IIS (Local). It's pretty much the same setup I use on our web server. Then I add the IP address I use and the hostname (URL) to the Windows hosts file. That allows me to have "live like" conditions. If you set in your web.config debug=true and customerrors mode= off then you get all the error details. There might be better ways, but I like it and it helps me a lot. You can go as far as exporting the SSL cert from the server and use it locally too. Hope it makes sense and helps you.

Comment: thanks @user11802287 this is what I've done and it works a treat.

Comment: I am glad to hear, Mark. Don't forget to undo the hosts file change when you are done. You would otherwise always see your development site. Talk from expirience.  Cheers KH

Answer (score 3):

I was attempting to work locally like your self and receiving the same issue. After speaking with support they confirmed that they will not accept "localhost". Also, the documentation suggests that HTTPS is a requirement, so this might also be a blocking factor.

I think someone suggested using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) as a means of tunneling external requests into your localhost, which is a good method to continue development locally whilst also being visible externally to services like SagePay.

Once I got passed the above issue, I got several more errors for other missing required fields as listed here; https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/38/psd2-under-direct-integration (note that if BrowserJavascriptEnabled is true all conditional fields are then required)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue and I wanted to document it here, because searching for this issue gives very little in terms of results.

I was getting this error code when i switched my Opayo/SagePay extension (MageNest SagePay for Magento) to 3ds2.

As it turns out, the full URL wasn't being sent. It was trying to send `sagepay/direct/postBack?form_key=HZuYxgiEq9w2CNFB` and NOT `https://www.example.com/sagepay/direct/postBack?form_key=HZuYxgiEq9w2CNFB`. It's partly my fault because there was a domain field in the config which was empty (it's not like the domain can't be retrieved automatically, huh) and partly the vendors fault because it was very *badly* documented.

So while this is a different problem for a different platform, I hope this helps someone.